# Qt Designer and Input method in two columns

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, qt-designer

Suppose i need to a `box-container or every name or term`, no differences. Important is my means:

Suppose I should `input my data` in `two columns`:

1. `attributes`
2. `values`

According to i'm newbie in `Qt Designer` , i don't know to choose which `widget`....!

Thank you for help befor it...!

Comment: I am sorry, English is not everybody's native language. I am not perfect myself. So please, no offense, but for me your question above is totally incomprehensible.

Comment: @Greenflow: I have to agree. The language barrier makes it difficult to understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need a map data structure

then use TableWidget to your map structure (I think table widget is what you want)

by the way you should make your hands dirty by programming what you want, then come to ask.